# Retrieve timerID on time based trigger invocation? BlackBerry 10

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I want to get the timerID for a time based trigger headless app. I get the trigger to fire and invoke the headless portion of my app, but the problem is that I cannot fetch the timerID.

Is there any way to get the timerID from the request? I've tried the following(generally):

```cpp
void Service::handleInvoke(const bb::system::InvokeRequest &request) {
    if (request.action().compare("bb.action.system.TIMER_FIRED") == 0) {
        // I've tried the following things and looked at their results in a saved setting 
        // but none give the timerID

        QString yo(request.data());
        settingzs.setValue("wheresthetimerid",yo);

        // and
        QVVariantMap metmet = request.metadata();    
        QString whatid = metmet["timerID"]; //also tried metmet[0] to no avail
        settingzs.setValue("wheresthetimerid",whatid);

        // and 
        request.uri()
        // and 
        request.listID() 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't seem that it is possible to get the timerID of the original [`InvokeTimerRequest`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__system__invoketimerrequest.html) when handling an invocation in the Cascades APIs.  Initially, I thought it might be possible to simply cast the [`InvokeRequest`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__system__invokerequest.html) to an [`InvokeTimerRequest`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__system__invoketimerrequest.html), but looking closely at the API definitions, these are separate classes and an `InvokeTimerRequest` is fundamentally different than an `InvokeRequest`.

An `InvokeTimerRequest` basically registers a timer for generating an invocation to a specific target, and when/each time the timer fires, a new distinct `InvokeRequest` object is created and sent.  It is [recommended to store the timerID](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__system__invoketimerrequest.html#function-timerid) when creating and registering the `InvokeTimerRequest`, since the timerID must be used to de-register the invoke timer if it is recurring.

If you really need to get the ID of the request, and you are willing to go lower level, this *might* be possible using the [BlackBerry Platform Services (BPS)](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/device_platform/bps/index.html) API to handle invoke events.  You would need to implement a BPS event loop in your service, and register to receive and handle [navigator events](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/core/com.qnx.doc.bps.lib_ref/topic/about_navigator__invoke_8h.html).  From the event you can retrieve the [`navigator_invoke_invocation_t`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/core/com.qnx.doc.bps.lib_ref/topic/navigator_invoke_invocation_t.html) structure describing the invocation, and you should be able to call [`navigator_invoke_invocation_get_id()`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/core/com.qnx.doc.bps.lib_ref/topic/navigator_invoke_invocation_get_id.html) to retrieve the ID of the `InvokeRequest`.

```cpp
switch (bps_event_get_code(event)) {
  case NAVIGATOR_INVOKE_TARGET: {
    const navigator_invoke_invocation_t *invoke = 
        navigator_invoke_event_get_invocation(event);
    // an invocation has been received
    if(invoke) {
      // retrieve invocation action
      QString action = navigator_invoke_invocation_get_action(invoke);
      if (action.compare("bb.action.system.TIMER_FIRED") == 0) {
        QString id = navigator_invoke_invocation_get_id(invoke);
      }
    }
  }
  break;
}
```

For a more C++ approach, you could create your own subclass of [`AbstractBpsEventHandler`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__abstractbpseventhandler.html) to handle this instead.

However, in the end the ID retrieved is most likely only the ID of the generated `InvokeRequest`, and not the timerID you specified when creating and registering the `InvokeTimerRequest`.